# 'Error enabling Google Cloud SQL' error occured

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to enable `Google Cloud SQL` for my application on GAE but every time I go to `API` section and press 'OFF' for `Google Cloud SQL` first I get pop up `Enabling Google Cloud SQL` like shown below

[image]

and then after few seconds I get `Error enabling Google Cloud SQL`.

[image]

Any idea why this error is coming? I am able to create SQL instances for my other applications but there seems to be some problem with this application only.

Please enlighten !!

Comment: Did you have billing enabled or credit card registered, without that it will not enable your Cloud SQL.

Comment: Yes billing is already enabled for this project.

Comment: Please reach out to cloud-sql@google.com including your project name. If possible please use your browser's developer tools to record the HTTP response containing the error, and include that.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll check HTTP response and error using chrome developer and let you know.